# Oracle query to create a table of counts between two columns

Tags: oracle

I have two columns of data in an Oracle database, one is a list of device types and the second is a column of sites. I am looking for a query (if possible) that would end up giving me a table with the distinct device types as the y axis and the sites as the x axis with the table of counts of how many of a device type at each site.

If I have:
device types = typeA, typeB, typeC, etc.
sites = site1, site2, site3, etc.

I want to end up with a table like this:

|  | site1 | site2 | site3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| typeA | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| typeB | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| typeC | 2 | 4 | 2 |

Is this doable with an Oracle query?

Comment: Regardless of the RDBMS, this cannot be done with a single query, because a query defines a result table, i.e. the columns must be known by the query. In your data, however, it is not known beforehand, how many sites there are. What you can do is write two queries: one that gets you the sites first, another you build dynamically from that first result.

Comment: You can if you are okay limiting the total number of possible sites to a discrete, reasonably low number. First you have to transform each comma delimited list into rows, then cartesian join them, then use nested MAX(DECODE()) to assemble your column list, but you have to pick a certain # of columns always have that many columns, leaving unused positions NULL. Or you can generate dynamic SQL.  However, all of these methods point to an underlying problem that you shouldn't have delimited lists in an RDBMS, they violate first normal form and as you can see are hard to work with.